# Use a variable to determine struct member

Tags: c++

In my code I'm using multiple structs of the following structure:

```
struct Track {
    string artist;                      
    string cd;                          
    // etc....  
};
```

The structs can be referred to as: Track1, Track2, etc. 
I'm trying to make a function that uses a variable to determine which member it should output.
For example:

```
string x ="cd"                                
cout << Track1.x << endl;
```

I can't really figure out how to do this... I keep getting the error that 'x' is not a member of the Struct.
Thanks for taking time to read this, I hope you can help me out.

Comment: What is your outer problem? Why do you need a function like this? How is it going to be called? What's wrong with code like `if (x == "cd") return o.cd;`?

Answer (score 7):

C++ is not a scripting language, so you can't do "variable variables" like that.

The usual way to do this is to use a map instead:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> myValues;
```

Then the following are the same:

```
std::cout << myValues["cd"] << std::endl;
```

and

```
std::string x = "cd";
std::cout << myValues[x] << std::endl;
```

However, I question your design. It seems like a track has a fixed number of properties so individual members make sense, rather than a map to which elements may be added and removed. You *could* restrict access to the map and write code that ensures it has all the track properties stored within it (and nothing else) at all times.

But I suggest revisiting the need for "variable variables" here in the first place. Passing a string into a function to determine its semantics doesn't seem particularly efficient, robust or resilient. Why not return a reference to the entire `Track` object, then the caller can examine any property they want?

```
std::cout << getTrack(arguments...).cd << std::endl;
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response!
I'm new to c++ so I really appreciate your explanations.
I'm sorry if it wasn't clear why I would use this method.
I removed some unessecary concepts to make the problem more readable.
I will take some time to understand/implement your awnsers and to explain the problem a bit better (i have some difficulties doing this in english).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify a class member by a *run-time* name. The only immediate language feature that allows one to specify a class member by a run-time value (i.e. as you put it "use a variable to determine struct member") is pointers of "pointer-to-member" type

```
Track track1 = { "Some Artist", "Some CD" };
Track track2 = { "Some Other Artist", "Some Other CD" };

std::string Track::*member = &Track::cd; // pointer-to-member points to 'cd' member
std::cout << track1.*member << std::endl;
std::cout << track2.*member << std::endl;

member = &Track::artist; // pointer-to-member points to 'artist' member
std::cout << track1.*member << std::endl;
std::cout << track2.*member << std::endl;
```

Now, if you want to be able to select a specific member using a string containing its name (as in your original post), you have no other choice but to implement the name-to-member mapping manually. You can use the aforementioned pointer-to-members to build such mapping

```
std::map<std::string, std::string Track::*> mapping = {
  { "artist", &Track::artist },
  { "cd", &Track::cd }
};

std::string Track::*member = mapping["cd"];
std::cout << track1.*member << std::endl;
std::cout << track2.*member << std::endl;
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response!
I'm new to c++ so I really appreciate your explanations.
I'm sorry if it wasn't clear why I would use this method.
I removed some unessecary concepts to make the problem more readable.
I will take some time to understand/implement your awnsers and to explain the problem a bit better (i have some difficulties doing this in english).